# Telegram API not allowing connection with my bot

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm trying to load the `getUpdates` method from Telegram, but it's not working. I've followed step by step the official documentation.

Some users had already posted questions similar to this one, but in their particular case, their problem was that they had forgotten to add `bot` before the token in the url. That's not my case, as you can see as follows:

This is my GET request in Postman:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<the token goes here>/getUpdates
```

And this is the response I receive:

```json
{
    "ok": false,
    "error_code": 404,
    "description": "Not Found"
}
```

Comment: The method is called [`getUpdates`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates)

Comment: @derpirscher I'm having this issue with `getUpdates` too

Comment: Do you have a webhook for updates? Are you sure your token is correct?

Comment: @derpirscher, I'm sure that my token is correct, but  I'm not using webhook, just wanted to make a get request from my Postman to check the connection